# url rewrite question

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hey, here is the example I have a question about. I have a link:

```
<a href='/index.php'>link</a>
```

Which will in turn go to `domain.com/index.php`

Now how would I make is so that with URL rewrite, it does NOT display index.html after?

I know i can just link to document root with "/" but this is not going to work in all cases for me. So a simple rewrite would be awesome!

Comment: Shouldn't need a rewrite: Just link to `domain.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index.php$ / [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also force if you can't influence the links like @Pekka suggested

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com [R=301,NC,L]
```